# Excel Formula for Inflation Adjusted Returns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

So for example: You want to receive $X in today's dollars at the beginning of each year for Z# of years.  Assuming a 3% constant inflation rate and a 7% compounded annual rate of return.
I know the formula to calculate the inflation adjusted returns; for the rate of return you have to use this formula:

```
[[(1+investment return)/(1+inflation rate)]-1]*100  OR in this instance
[(1.07/1.03)-1]*100
```

then you need to use the Present Value formula to calculate the rest `PV(rate,nper,pmt,[fv],[type])` to find out how much $ is needed to sustain $X adjusted for inflation for Z# years.  So here's my formula that I'm using:

```
=PV((((((1+E16)/(1+B15))-1)*100)),H14,-O7,,1)
```

Where E16 is my Annual Return (7%), B15 is my Inflation Rate (3), H14 is the number of years I need the payment (30), -O7 is my payment amount (made negative to give a positive #)($127,621.98), future value [fv] is left blank as is unnecessary, and Type is 1 so I calculate for receiving the payment at the beginning of the year.
What all this "should" return is $2,325,327.2044 according to my financial calculator, however Excel is giving me $160,484.6347.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: PERFECTION!  Thanks! @pnuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [syntax](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/pv-function-23879d31-0e02-4321-be01-da16e8168cbd) for PV includes:

> **Rate**    Required. The interest rate per period. For example, if you obtain an automobile loan at a 10 percent annual interest rate and make monthly payments, your interest rate per month is 10%/12, or 0.83%. You would enter 10%/12, or 0.83%, or 0.0083, into the formula as the rate.

So don't factor by `*100`.

Many parentheses serve no purpose as the formula below is sufficient:

```
=PV((1+E16)/(1+B15)-1,H14,-O7,,1)
```

The Excel (2013) result to four DP is: `$2,325,327.2045`.